# Tableau custom web-connector

Tags: csv, odbc, tableau-api

## Goal

At the moment I use Tableau for generating reports based on the data I store at KnackHQ (online database service, which has a REST API). I now have to **manually extract** data as Excel (or .csv) from KnackHQ to upload to Tableau. I would like to **automate** this process.

## Investigation

It seems there are several options to try:

1. Web-connector via ODBC (seems I need to write my own ODBC driver in my case, which can be tricky)
2. Export CSV (http://databoss.starschema.net/tableau-live-data-connection-to-csv-over-http-rest/)
3. OData (http://www.odata.org/)
4. Data Engine API (http://www.tableau.com/new-features/data-engine-api-0)
5. Any others?

Any ideas what can be the best method of such integration in terms of simplicity?

Comment: If the REST API of KnackHQ (I don't know it at all) is good, you can integrate with Tableau Data Engine API, to create .tde files. http://www.tableau.com/new-features/data-engine-api-0

Comment: The most preferred way for me would be no programming at all on Tableau side. As far as I see, the method you suggest requires programming on Tableau side "The API works with C/C++, Java, and Python and can be used from Windows"?

Comment: Yes, it does. In that case, you should find a KnackHQ forum, not a Tableau Forum. Your focus is on how to extract data from there, not on how to connect it on Tableau (which is pretty straightforward)

Comment: Shall I then go with OData way: program somewhere a bridge (accessible via URL) to transform data from Knack (within its API) to OData format?

Comment: As long as Tableau can easily connect to that format. I've never used OData. Make some tests first

Comment: Ifinally  decided to use Web-connector (which is in beta now) and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Tableau 9.1 (which will be released in 2015 Q3 but beta is already available) has a new feature: **Tableau Web Data Connector**. This is exactly what you need, since:

- You can build custom connectors using Tableau WDC Javascript API
- Create & refresh datasources in Tableau Desktop using these connectors
- Your administrator can import the connector. From that point Tableau Server can schedule and refresh the extracts based on your Web Service originated data

I would suggest to check out these post on how to write a new connector:

- [5 Things to Know about the Tableau 9.1 Web Data Connector](http://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2015/07/27/5-things-to-know-about-the-tableau-9-1-web-data-connector/)
- [Google Spreadsheet with Tableau Web Data Connector](http://databoss.starschema.net/google-spreadsheet-with-tableau-web-data-connector/)
- [MongoDB Tableau Web Data Connector](http://databoss.starschema.net/mongodb-web-data-connector-for-tableau/)
- [Github Tableau Web Data Connector](http://databoss.starschema.net/github-tableau-web-data-connector/)

You can also check official **Tableau Documentations** like how can you manage connectors: [Web Data Connectors in Tableau Server](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v9.1/server/en-us/help.htm#datasource_wdc.htm%3FTocPath%3DData%2520Sources%7CWeb%2520Data%2520Connectors%7C_____0)

If you want to try out this before it gets released please follow the instructions on the Tableau Community web site here: http://community.tableau.com/message/327560.